# Is there any way that Express proxy leaves the original url in all cases?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express Gateway to get SSL urls for a web application.

The gateway receives an url, cleans it by removing double slashes etc.

`https://server:port/aaaa/bbbb//cccc` becomes `https://server:port/aaaa/bbbb/cccc`.

The issue with this is that our application doesn't recognize the url/command.

Is there any way to leave the url as original?

Comment: how are you getting the url?
have you looked into  `req.originalUrl`?
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

According to express docs:

https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.router

You can pass to router options.
Passing `strict: true` will enable strict routing.

So create your router this way:

```js
const router = express.Router({
    strict: true
});

...
...

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: We have been trying with the strict property but it doesn't solve our problem.  I think that is this way because the '//' is inside the url and not at the end. Any idea is welcome